# MySQL BETWEEN with PDO prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query involving a `BETWEEN` statement and cannot see how to bind the parameters for it:

```
 try {
 include("../epsadmin/connectpdo.php");
 $sql="SELECT * FROM properties 
 WHERE location LIKE :location
 AND bedrooms LIKE :bedrooms
 AND category LIKE :category
 AND price BETWEEN :minPrice and :maxPrice 
 ORDER BY postcode";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':location', $_REQUEST['location'], PDO::STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':bedrooms', $_REQUEST['bedrooms'], PDO::STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':category', $_REQUEST['category'], PDO::STR);
//bindParam for price BETWEEN minPrice and MaxPrice needed
$stmt->execute();
$total = $stmt->rowCount();
$obj = $stmt->fetchObject();
}//end try 
catch(PDOException $error) {
$send='DB Query failed: ' . $error->getMessage(); 
header("Content-type: text/plain");
echo $send;
exit;
}
```

Could anybody help with the required `bindParam` statement?

Comment: You forgot the closing quote after `ORDER BY postcode`

Comment: Is `$stmt->bindParam(':minPrice', $_REQUEST['minPrice']);` and `$stmt->bindParam(':maxPrice', $_REQUEST['maxPrice']);` not working?

Comment: What is your problme with it?

Comment: yes as @mario.klump said it should work

Answer (score 0):

> how to do the prepared statement for a query involving a BETWEEN statement

Exactly the same way as with any other query: By adding the necessary placeholders to the query and then by binding them using the `bindParam` method.

Comment: Probably not your intention but it looks like a blunt answer